# Sorting list of Wikipedia links

Tags: python, perl, http, bash, wikipedia

I have a long list of Wikipedia links in a plaintext file. Each link is separated by a newline and is percent-encoded. Unfortunately a large number of these links are outdated; some are redirects and others have been removed. Is there anyway to automatically sort through the links, resolving redirects and removing dead links?

A bash/python script would be nice, but any other working implementation is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

python `mechanize` is nice:

```
import mechanize

links = [
"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain",
"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dari",
"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobnab"
]

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')] # A white lie

for link in links:
    print link
    try:
        br.open(link)
        page_name = br.title()[:-35].replace(" ", "_")
        if page_name != link.split("/")[-1]:
            print "redirected to:", page_name
        else:
            print "page OK"
    except mechanize.URLError:
        print "error: dead link"
```

Comment: This seems to be doing what I want! However is it possible to just output the correct URL rather than the article title? e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dari_(Persian) rather than just `Dari (Persian)'? The `correct' relative URL is in the <head> of each article if it helps, as <link rel="canonical" href="/wiki/..." />

Comment: You can always just add the missing bit back: `url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + page_name`. The browser object has a `.geturl()` method, but this returns the url you entered, not the redirected one.

Comment: Only problem there is that I need to replace spaces with underscores. But since that can be done in any text editor, it's a moot point. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Kudos for using mechanize.  That was my first thought when reading this question too.  Also, Ashton, replacing spaces with underscores should be a trival task within the Python script as well.  You could try something like page_name = page_name.replace(' ', '_').

Comment: I feel a bit bad about blabbing the `br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]` trick. Don't abuse this, Stack-Overflowers!

Answer (score 4):

It should be easy with Perl and [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;    

open my $fh, "links.txt" or die $!;
my @links = <$fh>;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

for my $link (@links) {
    my $resp = $ua->get($link); # automatically follows redirects    
    if ($resp->is_success) {
        print $resp->request->uri, "\n";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not check if a link is a redirect, but will check all the links. Redirects will be deemed valid links (as long as the redirected page is found, obviously). Just fix the print what ever way you want to get the output you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from urllib import urlopen

f = open('links.txt', 'r')

valid = []
broken = []

for line in f:
  try:
    urlopen(line)
    valid = valid + [line]
  except:
    broken = broken + [line]

for link in valid:
  print "VALID: " + link

for link in broken:
  print "BROKEN: " + link
```

If you want to know which valid links are redirects, you can probably do it with urllib.FancyURLopener(), but I have never used it so can't be certain.

Comment: This currently reports non-existent links as VALID.

Comment: Ah, it looks like Wikipedia actually redirects invalid pages. Sorry, I don't have time to write a better version right now, but I'll see if I can do it tomorrow.

Comment: Michael's solution seems to work, so I won't try come up with an alternative.